# Where should i put SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 in vb.net 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this so far:

```
Dim sqlconn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
sqlconn.Open()

da.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, sqlconn)
da.Fill(ds)
ds.WriteXml(CurDir() & "\SummaryReport.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
MsgBox("XML created!", vbInformation)
```

where should I put `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1`? I really don't know since I'm new in vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Dim sqlconn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
da.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;" & sql, sqlconn)
da.Fill(ds) 'da.Fill() will open and close the connection for you
ds.WriteXml(CurDir() & "\SummaryReport.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
MsgBox("XML created!", vbInformation)
```